# How many bit strings of length $n$ are there such that every initial segment has more $0$'s than $1$'s?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, for $n=3$, there are two:

$$\begin{align}
000, 001
\end{align}$$

Let $T(n)$ be the amount of such strings for a given string length $n$. It's clear that $$\begin{align}
T(n) \le 2T(n-1)
\end{align}$$

This is because a new valid string can only be selected from the set of strings created by concatenating a $0$ or $1$ to the valid strings of length $n-1$.

Representing the problem with a binary tree has led me to postulate that if $n$ is odd, then $T(n) = 2T(n-1)$, however the case for $n$ being even is much less clear.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: I was going to note in my question that it seems similar to the Dyck word counting, but they are different problems. Dyck words always have an equal amount of 0's and 1's. Maybe they're related but I haven't found the relation yet.

Comment: Ah yes, there is a bit of a difference there. Perhaps it's not so simple...

Comment: This is just an instance of the ballot problem, have a look at the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by Jack D'Aurizio, this is an instance of [Bertrand's ballot theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem). This theorem proves that the proportion of all bit strings of length $n=p+q$ with $p$ zeroes and $q$ ones for which all initial segments have more zeroes than ones is $\frac{p-q}n$. Since there are ${n\choose q}$ strings all together, this implies that there are $\frac{p-q}n{n\choose q}$ strings including the biased initial segments condition.

The total number of bit strings for any choice of $p,q$ satisfying $p+q=n$ is then $$T(n)=\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\frac{n-2q}n{n\choose q}=\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}{n-1\choose q}-{n-1\choose q-1}={n-1\choose\lfloor n/2\rfloor},$$

since the sum telescopes. And since $${2k\choose k}=\frac{2k}k{2k-1\choose k}=2\cdot{2k-1\choose k},$$

this verifies the claim that $T(2k+1)=2T(2k)$, with the corresponding relation for even $n$ being $T(2k)=(2-\frac1k)T(2k-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jack D'Aurizio for the tip.

Let $p$ be the number of $0$'s and $q$ the number of $1$'s in a string of length $n=p + q$, with $p \gt q$. The number of valid strings $V(p,q)$ is given by:

$$\begin{align}
V(p,q)={p+q-1 \choose p-1}-{p+q-1 \choose p}={n-1 \choose p-1}-{n-1 \choose p}\
\end{align}$$

Therefore to find all strings of length $n$, all valid pairs of $p$ and $q$ must be summed. Let $A(n) = \{\ (p,q) : p + q = n;\  p > q \  \}$. We then have:

$$\begin{align}
T(n)= \sum_{(p,q) \in A(n) }V(p,q)
\end{align}$$

Let $m$ be the lowest possible value for $p$ for a given $n$. We have:

$$\begin{align}
T(n)&=\sum_{i=m}^{n-1}\left({n-1 \choose i-1}-{n-1 \choose i}\right) + 1 \\
 &=\left({n-1 \choose m-1}-{n-1 \choose n-1}\right) + 1 \\
&= {n-1 \choose m-1}
\end{align}$$

Note that when $p = n$, $V(p,q)=1$, so instead of summing to $i=n$, we replaced it with $1$.

For odd $n$, $m=\lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$, and for even $n$, $m=\frac{n}{2}+1$.

This was a surprising answer to me, given how simple it ended up!